# Why isn't SSAS loading any measure data for my cube?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssas, msas

Background:

I'm writing a data provider that SSAS will use to get data from a third-party system.
I wrote a tool that will build cubes, dimensions, measure groups and measures based on the configuration of the third-party system using AMO.

Now, in the Cube Browser, I am able to pull the members of the dimensions, however, measure data is never queried - I know this because my data provider will log all SQL queries SSAS requests from it.

So, how do I diagnose this? What are the configuration steps for measures (this is just a regular, 1:1 measure against a single-key dimension - VERY simple cube).

As far as I can tell, my relationships are the same as a working dimension and measure, and I don't get any errors from SSAS or the event logs, just silence and a set of empty cells in the Cube browser.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my issue.

When I created the measure group using AMO, I never created a partition for it. Measure groups without partitions will deploy and process without errors, but nothing will be queried because the relationship to the fact table doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

To correct Calculations:

In cube Calculations tab, , make sure you are on script view (as opposed to form view).  Write the word CALCULATE in the script area.  Click back to the Browser tab to verify that you now have measure data.

Thanks for the direction, Ian!

Answer (score 2):

CALCULATE; command was not present in the Scripts/Calculations tab. Solved and it works

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/about, to get more understanding about questions/answers here on SO. Your contribution is not answering the question. It is more a comment, to other answer. You can add a comment once you'll increase your reputation: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation

Answer (score 1):

For others:

- Check if the *CALCULATE;* command is present in the Scripts/Calculations tab.
- Ensure that you specify the relationship between dimensions and measure groups.
- Set any related dimension UnknownMember properties to Visible.

More suggestions [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/sqlanalysisservices/thread/7692e602-aa32-4e4a-8519-04e1a99c0111) and [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic868996-147-1.aspx)